# Group by with in Group by using dataframe python panda

Tags: pandas, dataframe

For the give piece of data from .csv file i want to get groupby and get sum of the amount by using following rule.

Note that some categories, such as “Cloud Security” needed to be composed / summed from categories such as: Cloud Security, Cloud Computing, and Cloud Data Services to come up with “Cloud Security Overall.” Similarly, “Blockchain and Cryptocurrencies” is a sum of Blockchain, Virtual Currency, Bitcoin, and Etherium.

[image: Input]

[image: Required Output]

My Code:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame({'Categories' : ['Blockchain,Cloud Computing,InformationTechnology,Software', 'Cyber Security,Fraud Detection,Information Technology,Network Security', 'Information Technology,Medical,Security,Virtual Currency,Telecommunications', 'Mobile,Mobile Devices, Security,Bitcoin',
                      'Computer,Cyber Security,Network Security', 'Accounting,Hardware,Security,Software,Cloud data Service', 'Content,Security,Software,Etherium', 'Cyber Security,Enterprise Software,Security'],
               'Amount' : [500, 400, 700, 900, 100, 800, 1000,600]})
print(tmp)



dfc = tmp.groupby(tmp['Categories'])['Amount'].sum().reset_index()
dfc.columns =['Categories', 'Amount']
```

this code just give over all group by and sum

Comment: kindly provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i have added code of df

Comment: Do you have the grouping defined anywhere, how do I know what all makes up Cloud Security  Overall?

Comment: that is on the top of the page, in Note section. i also give color green and red

Comment: how you are distributing amount?since In row at index 0 what should it is considered as it contains both Blockchain and  Cloud computing?

Comment: No, this full amount should added into both categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Categories':['Blockchain, Cloud Computing, Information Technology, Software',
                                'Cyber Security, Fraud Detection, Information Tehnology, Network Security',
                                'Information Technology, Medical, Security, Virtual Currency, Telecommunications',
                                'Mobile, Mobile Devices, Security, Bitcoin',
                                'Computer, Cyber Security, Network Security',
                                'Accounting, Hardware, Security, Software, Cloud data Service', 
                                'Content, Security, Software, Etherium',
                                'Cyber Security, Enterprise Software, Security'],
                  'Amount':[500,400,700,900,100,800,1000,600]})

dfe = df.assign(Cats=df['Categories'].str.split(',\s+?')).explode('Cats')

dd = {'Cyber Security': 'Cloud Security Overall',
      'Cloud Computing' : 'Cloud Security Overall',
      'Cloud data Service' : 'Cloud Security Overall',
      'Blockchain' : 'Blockchain and Cyptocurrencies',
      'Virtual Currency' : 'Blockchain and Cyptocurrencies',
      'Bitcoin' : 'Blockchain and Cyptocurrencies',
      'Etherium' : 'Blockchain and Cyptocurrencies'}

print(dfe.groupby(dfe['Cats'].map(dd))['Amount'].sum())
```

Output:

```
Cats
Blockchain and Cyptocurrencies    3100
Cloud Security Overall            2400
Name: Amount, dtype: int64
```

#### Update per comments, did you want?

```
dfe.groupby(dfe['Cats'].replace(dd))['Amount'].sum()
```

Output:

```
Cats
Accounting                         800
Blockchain and Cyptocurrencies    3100
Cloud Security Overall            2400
Computer                           100
Content                           1000
Enterprise Software                600
Fraud Detection                    400
Hardware                           800
Information Technology            1200
Information Tehnology              400
Medical                            700
Mobile                             900
Mobile Devices                     900
Network Security                   500
Security                          4000
Software                          2300
Telecommunications                 700
Name: Amount, dtype: int64
```

Or

```
dfe.groupby(dfe['Cats'].map(dd).fillna('Rest'))['Amount'].sum()
```

Output:

```
Cats
Blockchain and Cyptocurrencies     3100
Cloud Security Overall             2400
Rest                              15300
Name: Amount, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Oh one more thing, i want to keep rest of the categories as it is... Let suppose one category doesnt fall into one of these so, i want to keep this as it is.